# How can I scrape nodes text from a javascript Piechart graph using Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, graph, beautifulsoup

How can I scrape nodes from a javascript Piechart graph using Python like this?

https://www.dice.com/skills/javascript

[Piechart graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iudS.png)

Hint: I want the scraped texts from the graph represent the graph nodes, not ordinary texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the page is rendered via `JavaScript` so we can use `selenium` or using `requests` and `bs4` because the desired output is located in `script` tag which can be captured with `regex`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get(
    'https://www.dice.com/skills/javascript')

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("div", {'class': 'node'}):
    print(item.text)
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
JavaScript
CSS
HTML5
jQuery
jQuery UI
AngularJS
Bootstrap
jQuery
jQuery UI
CSS
HTML5
AngularJS
Ajax
jQuery UI
jQuery
Aptana
Zend Studio
Ajax
CSS
AngularJS
jQuery
HTML5
HTML
Bootstrap
CSS
Node.js
React.js
MongoDB
AngularJS
Express.js
NoSQL
```

Updated:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get("https://www.dice.com/skills/javascript")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

script = soup.findAll("script")[8].get_text("\t", strip=True)

start = script.find("{")
end = script.find(";")

print(script[start:end])
```

Output:

```
{"name":"JavaScript","children":[{"name":"CSS","children":[{"name":"HTML5"},{"name":"jQuery"},{"name":"jQuery UI"},{"name":"AngularJS"},{"name":"Bootstrap"}]},{"name":"jQuery","children":[{"name":"jQuery UI"},{"name":"CSS"},{"name":"HTML5"},{"name":"AngularJS"},{"name":"Ajax"}]},{"name":"jQuery UI","children":[{"name":"jQuery"},{"name":"Aptana"},{"name":"Zend Studio"},{"name":"Ajax"},{"name":"CSS"}]},{"name":"AngularJS","children":[{"name":"jQuery"},{"name":"HTML5"},{"name":"HTML"},{"name":"Bootstrap"},{"name":"CSS"}]},{"name":"Node.js","children":[{"name":"React.js"},{"name":"MongoDB"},{"name":"AngularJS"},{"name":"Express.js"},{"name":"NoSQL"}]}]}
```

Comment: Great, but I want a way in which these scraped texts represent the graph nodes, not ordinary texts.

Can you help me ?

Comment: I mean a data structure includes these graph nodes like this one:

{
"Javascript" : ['AngularJS','Node.js','CSS','jQuery',jQuery UI'],
"AngularJS": ['jQuery','HTML5','HTML',Bootstrap', 'CSS'],
"Node.js": ['React.js', 'MongoDB', 'AngularJS', Express.js', 'NoSQL'],
.
.

}